# Seemingly random disconnections on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008, connection

So I have a box running a Windows Server 2008 R2 in my LAN, which is running, among other things, a voip server used by other people. I myself am in the same subnet with the server, while the other users are not.

Now, maybe on average twice a day, all the other users get disconnected from the server (and if I take a remote desktop connection to it, I'm not able to open any web pages either). These disconnections usually last only about 5 seconds, but sometimes they may last up to a minute. What could possibly cause this?

I have all the updates installed from windows update and the motherboard of the server is asus p5b deluxe (if that is of any interest).

edit: Forgot to mention that my own internet connectivity stays intact while the server's does not, and both computers are behind the same router.

Comment: I am having similar problem with my Win Server 2008r2 on poweredge 2800 and was posted on the server fault website. [Server Fault Link (Closed)](http://serverfault.com/questions/335489/poweredge-2800-drops-off-network)

Answer (score 0):

How many users are on the server?

What roles does it host?

Are there network shares?

Your best get is to hookup a network monitor and setup perfmon on the server to gather as much information as possible to narrow down the cause. This could be hardware.

As far as we know, it could be a hamster falling of its wheel.

Comment: The server has about 10 users. No network shares. And yes I was considering it being hardware as well, but the thing is I was using the very same motherboard on my desktop until last month, which was when I got a new one and used the old one for the server.

Comment: Oh and also, the motherboard has 2 network interfaces. I've tried them both, and they both behave the same.